# Trigger.io does not open

Tags: trigger.io

I am evaluating trigger.io. I have a Ubuntu machine and have Windows XP on a Virtual Machine on it. I installed trigger.io tool kit in Windows XP VM instance and started working on the weather demo app. Finished the first chapter and worked perfectly fine, even installed it on my iPhone as well. However, couple of days down the line suddenly now when I start trigger.io tool kit, the page opens up in the browser but no options for config or forge visible. How do I figure out why this is not starting ( I even re-installed the tool kit but the same result). Is there a log that I can read to find more information? I have attached the screen to show how it looks like. I will appreciate help in fixing this.

[image]

After uninstalling the older version and installing the new one, now the "Loading" image shows up and just keeps going on.
[image]

Here is what I find in the toolkit.log file -

`2013-01-13 19:09:55,515 [trigger.web:   INFO] Attempting to open browser...
2013-01-13 19:09:56,312 [trigger.session:   INFO] 0 sessions: []`

Here is the JS console -

`Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://toolkit-local.com:38394/static/manifest.appcache
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache NoUpdate event
Created session with id:  40cb230c-f9e3-45e2-8841-4430cbcf5a2b remote.js:161`

Here are bunch of errors in JS console when I tried to access it in IE 8 (generally I never use IE) -

`Object doesn't support this property or method  toolkit-local.com:38394, line 6 character 4
  Expected identifier  config.js, line 171 character 28
LOG: Created session with id: d55f077f-2c40-4fcc-b7c7-0f7e2e9c7355
  Unexpected call to method or property access.  jquery-1.7.js, line 5828 character 5
  Object doesn't support this property or method  toolkit.js, line 68 character 4
  Object doesn't support this property or method  toolkit-local.com:38394, line 6 character 4
  Expected identifier, string or number  views.js, line 569 character 3
  'Toolkit.Views.ViewWithTemplate' is null or not an object  form.js, line 6 character 2
  Expected identifier  config.js, line 171 character 28
  'undefined' is null or not an object  console.js, line 198 character 2
  'Toolkit.Views.ViewWithTemplate' is null or not an object  plugins.js, line 198 character 2
  'Toolkit.Views.ViewWithTemplate' is null or not an object  projects.js, line 38 character 2
LOG: Created session with id: 979c4bde-1426-44ef-8992-e47eab0e7c60
  'JSON' is undefined  remote.js, line 226 character 2
  Object doesn't support this property or method  toolkit-local.com:38394, line 6 character 4
  Expected identifier  config.js, line 171 character 28
LOG: Created session with id: b279d926-0282-4091-a31a-879fbb766efd
  Unexpected call to method or property access.  jquery-1.7.js, line 5828 character 5
  Object doesn't support this property or method  toolkit.js, line 68 character 4`

Comment: OK, the Toolkit has been updated in your second screenshot, but there's obviously still something wrong: could you check the JavaScript console for errors? (Ctrl-Shift-J)

Comment: I checked the Java Script console but there wasn't any obvious error on it. I will be able to upload it little later as I don't have access right now but will do so soon.

Comment: James, I have edited the post with JS console message. Please let me know if that helps figure out anything.

Comment: You should try the source version of Toolkit, I use it on a daily basis on my Debian 6. You only need Python 2.7, Java SDK & Android Development tools

Comment: This is turning out very frustrating as there is nothing in the logs that points to what's the problem in launching the toolkit page. I guess I will have to bring down the VM image all together and re-create, then re-install the trigger.io to rule out all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a slightly out of date version of the Toolkit (we released a new version last week). It should update itself but it looks like something has gone wrong here.

Can you try first uninstalling the current Toolkit you have then downloading a new copy of the Toolkit from https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit/ and reinstalling.

If that doesn't work there should be a log file in `C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\toolkit.log` with more information.

Comment: Tried uninstalling old version and re-installing new one. But still facing issues. Please check the updated screen shot if you would be able to provide any other suggestion.